# How can I create a plugin to input math formulas in Notepad++?

Tags: c++, notepad++

I would like to be able to input some math formula in Notepad++.

I'm trying to get something close to the Microsoft equation (but much simpler)

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do so?

Update 1:

I did some more research and one solution would be to write a math editor instead... I have no idea where or How to start, can someone give me some guidance ?? I mostly write in C++ 
a tutorial on how to write a math editor  in c++ would be great

Comment: Notepad++ is a *plain text* editor. It isn’t compatible with formulas. Full stop.

Comment: Do you what to draw the formulas using the ASCII characters, or what?

Comment: Are you intending for the input to be evaluated?

Comment: It might not be what you are asking about.. If you are trying to have math formulas in the comments and you are using doxygen, you can write them as LaTeX math expressions and the generated doxygen documentation of your code will have nice looking math formulas as a result (i.e. you can use LaTeX math in a LaTeX-generated doxygen code documentation).

Comment: Is MathPad the kind of thing you're after? https://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/482781/topic/3544403

Comment: Have you heard of Latex? Its the long standing standard for writing scientific papers with good equation support. Vscode has nice plugins for it. And sites like Overleaf even give live rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want equations for quick access *within your code* so that you don't have to consistently type them, I'm pretty sure there is no way to import those from Notepad++. As Konrad said, it is a plain text editor.

If your intention is for reusable equations, then you could write your own header (such as equations.h).
For instance, say you want to make a reusable quadratic equation yourself, you could make a header file program:

```
static double quadratic(double a, double b, double c)
{

  double x;
    x = (-b + sqrt(pow(b, 2) - (4*a*c))) / (2*a) ;
   return x ;
}
```

And so long as you put the header file in your program directory and make sure you #include "equations.h", you could call any equations you make in this header.

Comment: This formula is numerically bad, since when 4ac << b it will lose precision dramatically.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph  yep i know but i was wondering if it was possible to improve on that

Comment: @mellamokb not in a first time, i just want to be able to display the formula

Comment: @Andrejs Cainikovs  well i have been told to create a special font